# Symfony2 Orderby specific field value first

Tags: sql, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

Symfony2 When Case is not working.

Want to Ordering by specific field value first

```
$query->select('s.firstName as first_name,s.lastName as last_name,sts.name as status_name')
            ->leftJoin('s.studentStatus', 'sts')
            ->where($query->expr()->orx(
                $query->expr()->like('s.internalId', ':internalId'),
            ))
            ->addSelect('(CASE WHEN s.storeID = :location THEN 1 else 2) AS HIDDEN storeOrder')
            ->setParameter('internalId', "%{$internalId}")
            ->setParameter('location', "{$location}")
            ->orderBy('storeOrder', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults((int) $limit);
```

Want to order by a column specific value first, other values come after that. I have SQL Query but its not working with below Syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CASE construction is vendor specific and not part of Doctrine 2 by default. However you can have a look into the [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions). You can use the IfElse function for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an hidden field `storeOrder` then order by this field:

```
$query->select('s.firstName as first_name,s.lastName as last_name,sts.name as status_name')
           ->leftJoin('s.studentStatus', 'sts')
            ->where($query->expr()->orx(
                $query->expr()->like('s.internalId', ':internalId'),
            ))
            ->addSelect('(CASE WHEN s.storeID = :location THEN 1 else 2) AS HIDDEN storeOrder')
            ->setParameter('name', "%{$term}%")
            ->setParameter('internalId', "%{$internalId}")
            ->setParameter('location', "{$location}")
            ->orderBy('storeOrder', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults((int) $limit);
```

Comment: Do i have to use the extension, do you know the process of use extension in repository, can you share information.